# Problem attaching the door of the storage unit of a IKEA MALM desk

Tags: doors, hinges, desk

I recently bought and assembled a MALM desk. The assembly went smoothly with no issue until the last step where I need to attach the door.

The hinges and the brackets are screwed in in their right spot. I managed to fit the hinges in the bracket and slided them right but then it's impossible to tighten the screw on the bracket in order to firmly attach the door. The screw can only be loosened and tightening to the maximum leaves a wide space between the hinge and the bracket so the door is left hanging and unattached.

I've been struggling with the problem all night so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a picture please?

Answer (score 1):

There are two screws that are NOT for fastening, but for adjustment. They are on top of the hinge, and are visible even after assembly. The hinge clicks into its bracket. These screws are for alignment of the door.

And there are other screws for fastening. They are on the hinge bracket, and screw into the wood. These are not visible after assembly.

Can you add a picture please? Let's get that cleared up first.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Each hinge has 4 screws that allow you to move the door in 6 directions.  One of the screws does exactly what you describe, it moves the door left and right. Go to youtube and search "adjust ikea door", you'll become an expert in 5 minutes.